# Adding www to website urls during validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently when adding a url via a form on my Rails app we have the following `before_save` and `validation` checks:

```
def smart_add_url_protocol
  if self.website?
    unless self.website[/\Ahttp:\/\//] || self.website[/\Ahttps:\/\//]
      self.website = "http://#{self.website}"
    end
  end
end

validates_format_of :website, :with => /^((http|https):\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+).[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.)?$/ix, :multiline => true
```

However, what this means is that if I type into the form field

```
testing.com
```

It tells me that the url is invalid and I'd have to put in

```
www.testing.com
```

for it to accept the url

I would like it to accept the url whether or not a user enters www or http.

Should I add something else to the smart_add_url_protocol to ensure this is added, or is this an issue with the validation?

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

There is a standard [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class which can be used for checking `url`s. In your case you need [URI::regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-regexp) method. Using it your class can be rewritten like this:

```
before_validation :smart_url_correction
validate :website, :website_validation

def smart_url_correction
  if self.website.present?
    self.website = self.website.strip.downcase
    self.website = "http://#{self.website}" unless self.website =~ /^(http|https)/
  end
end

def website_validation
  if self.website.present?
    unless self.website =~ URI.regexp(['http','https'])
      self.errors.add(:website, 'illegal format')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks - have changed the code as per your advice, but it's still telling me that the website is invalid without the www part. Do I need to change something in this line too? validates_format_of :website, :with => /^((http|https):\/\/)?[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+).[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.)?$/ix, :multiline => true

Comment: Remove this validation. You don't need it with the code above.